# Set up training pipeline without removing a column in ML.NET

Tags: c#, ml.net

I copied some code from a tutorial on how to set up and train an ML model in .NET, in the example it removes a column using 'DropColumns' when it sets up the pipeline, how do I set up the pipeline without removing a column? I tried just adding a dummy column and removing it and while it trains fine, when I go to use the model it complains that column is missing.

```
var mlContext = new MLContext();

        // set up a text loader
        var textLoader = mlContext.Data.CreateTextLoader(
            new Microsoft.ML.Data.TextLoader.Options()
            {
                Separators = new[] { ',' },
                HasHeader = true,
                AllowQuoting = true,
                Columns = new[]
                {
                new TextLoader.Column("rdate", DataKind.Single, 0),
                new TextLoader.Column("one", DataKind.Single, 0),
                new TextLoader.Column("two", DataKind.Single, 0),
                ...

        var trainingDataView = textLoader.Load(trainingDataPath);
        var testDataView = textLoader.Load(testDataPath);

        var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.DropColumns("two")
```

Comment: You can just remove that transform from the pipeline. Is there more to it, though, or is that all that was in that pipeline?

Comment: I .append some things  to it after. If I just do: var pipeline = mlContext - it comes up the error: 'MLContext does not contain a definition for append....'

Comment: Just remove the entire `mlContext.Transforms.DropColumns` from the pipeline and it should be good to go

Comment: So what do I set the pipeline to then? var pipeline on it's own doesnt work.

Comment: You would use the rest of the pipeline, like `var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.DropColumns("Name", "Cabin", "Ticket")` and add the others with the `Append` method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just
`var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms`?

Can you post a link to the tutorial?

Comment: I tried that, it says: } expected. Tutorial is here: https://medium.com/machinelearningadvantage/predicting-your-chances-of-surviving-the-titanic-disaster-with-c-and-ml-net-machine-learning-9b69bc3997d5

Comment: @user2096512 Do you close this part `new Microsoft.ML.Data.TextLoader.Options()
            {` with a }?

Comment: Yes, I do, I left it out as there is a lot of code.

Comment: @user2096512 Was just a guess based on the error `} expected`